# Initializing variables with imported tensors from another graph

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow (version : v1.1.0-13-g8ddd727 1.1.0) in python3 (Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) [GCC 4.8.4] on linux), it is installed from source and GPU-based.

I would like to know if it is possible to initialize variables with imported tensors from another session, as tensorflow documentations does not mention it and I have found it on stackoverflow.

```
train_dir = './gan/train_logs'
    ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir)
    filename = ".".join([ckpt, 'meta'])
    print(filename)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(filename)
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt)
    test = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='generator')
```

Here the tensors are successfully imported and I want to use them to initialize same generator.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to create tf.assign ops.

So you do :

```
old_weights = .... # your loading

new_weights = tf.Variable( ... ) # any initialisation here!

initialise_new_weights = tf.assign(new_weights, old_weights)

with tf.train.MonitoredSession() as sess:
  # at this point new_weights are randomly initialised
  sess.run(initialise_new_weight) # now they are initialised to your values
```

or you can pass initialiser argument directly

```
old_weights = .... # your loading

new_weights = tf.Variable( ..., initializer = tf.constant_initialiser(old_weights) ) 

with tf.train.MonitoredSession() as sess:
  # they are initialised to your values
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It actually worked! The problem was definitely this tf.assign and I did not realize I had to run it as an op.